# How to run Ubuntu service on Windows (at startup)?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, windows-10-v1607, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to launch an SSH server on Linux subsystem (Bash on Ubuntu on Windows) at windows startup. The problem is that all Linux processes are terminated when Bash window is closed.

Is there a way to make Linux process run permanently in background without bash window?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Found a tutorial for that by aseering:

This was originally discussed and sorted out by github users imjakey, fpqc, qris, therealkenc, Manouchehri, and aseering (myself) here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/612

Note that running sshd has security implications. Until WSL's security model has had longer to bake, you should assume that anyone who can ssh into your Windows box has permission to perform any command as the Windows user running sshd, regardless of Linux-level permissions. (Permissions are probably more restrictive than that in practice, but WSL's initial security model is not intended to be very sophisticated.)

Attempting to aggregate the instructions from github:

- Generate SSH host keys by running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure
  openssh-server` in a bash shell
- Run `sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config`;
  edit the `UsePrivilegeSeparation yes` line to read
  `UsePrivilegeSeparation no`. (This is necessary because
  `UsePrivilegeSeparation` uses the `chroot()` syscall, which WSL
  doesn't currently support.)
- While still editing
  `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, you may choose to change
  `PasswordAuthentication no` to `PasswordAuthentication yes`.
  Otherwise you will have to set up SSH keys.
- Save
  `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and exit.
- Run `sudo visudo` to edit the
  sudoers file. Add the line

  ```
  $USER ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/sshd -D
  ```

  replacing "$USER" with your Linux username. Save
  and exit. If visudo complains that your changes are invalid, fix them
  until it reports that they are valid; otherwise you can break sudo on
  your system!
- On the Windows side, edit the Windows firewall (and any
  third-party firewalls that you might be running) to allow incoming
  traffic on port 22. Because this isn't a super-secure setup, I
  recommend only allowing incoming traffic from home (private) and
  domain networks, not from the public Internet.
- Create a text file
  `autostartssh.vbs` in Windows containing the following:

  ```
  set ws=wscript.createobject("wscript.shell")
  ws.run "C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -c 'sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -D'",0
  ```

  - Double-click on the script. It should start sshd; you should be able to ssh into your Windows machine.
  - Open Windows's Task Scheduler. Add a task that runs `autostartssh.vbs` on system boot. Use `wscript.exe` as the command to run and the VBS script location as the parameter.

And that's it -- your Windows computer should be running a Linux openssh server!

Comment: The VBS script didn't do anything for me. sshd isn't showing up in resource monitor Network tab.

Comment: I wrote a a process dispatcher https://github.com/131/dispatcher that 'll allows you to spawn bash with no windows.

Comment: @megamaiku: I had the same problem. Turns out the little snipped to run sshd got stuck on the (invisible) password prompt because I didn't do the "visudo" part right. At first I added the NOPASSWD line somewhere in the middle of the sudoers file. It worked once I moved it to the bottom!

Comment: It's currently working with `UsePrivilegeSeparation = yes` , except that one needs to also run `sudo /bin/mkdir -p /var/run/sshd` (to create the privilege separation directories) before starting sshd. Does WLS now support chroot(), is there a workaround in place in the openssh source, or is the `= No` setting more of a safety recommendation? Also, the windows task seems to only work for me if my user is logged in.

Comment: This worked excellently. I would suggest, to make things easier, move the port SSH is listening on, e.g. 3322, something random. Comment out the line in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` that reads `Port 22` and switch to `Port 8822`. One reason for this is Windows running some sort of SSH process on 22. I've seen suggestions saying there's no problem with disabling that, but I found it easiest to just switch the WSL SSH port.

Answer (score 22):

1. Create a file named `wsl_setup.bat` and add content as follow

   ```
   wsl -u root -e sudo service ssh start
   wsl -u root -e sudo service nginx start
   ```
2. Add `wsl_setup.bat` file to windows startup folder [windows-10-change-startup-apps](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026268/windows-10-change-startup-apps)
3. Restart and log in your windows account (yes, you need to log in)

Comment: This is best answer, We can change which distrib we want to run the command on by adding `-d Debain` where Debain can be replaced by any name of distro installed, which one can obtain by running `wsl -l`.

Comment: **Important note:** Do not name the `.bat` file like the command you are using inside (eg. `wsl.bat`)

Comment: Awesome answer! Had to lookup (thanks for the link) how to get to the startup folder. TLDR; is `WIN+R` then `shell:startup`. Pretty easy.

Comment: While a good answer for the general use case, this honestly doesn't address the original question.  The OP asked how to do this at Windows *boot*, not login.  The accepted answer (using `wscript`), as well as @Nom's suggestion to autologin, are ways to do this.

Answer (score 4):

I've needed to do the same thing.

Here's how to boot the Ubuntu Linux subsystem with all of cron's services upon the Windows boot & provide a means to 'reboot' the Linux subsystem.

I'm successfully hosting the openssh-server, nginx & mariadb database on our server.

**Install Linux Subsystem**

- Open Powershell as Administrator
- Paste:

  ```
  Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
  ```
- Install Ubuntu from Windows Store.

**Remove sudo password prompt (required)**

- Open bash (Linux Subsystem installs this)
- Paste:

  ```
  sudo sed -i "s/%sudo.*/%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL/g" /etc/sudoers
  ```

**Enable SSH password login (optional)**

- Open bash
- Paste:

  ```
  sudo sed -i '/StrictModes yes/c\StrictModes no' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
  sudo sed -i '/ChallengeResponseAuthentication/c\ChallengeResponseAuthentication no' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
  sudo sed -i '/PasswordAuthentication/c\PasswordAuthentication yes' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
  ```

**Windows autologin on start (required if you have a password or RDP in)**

- Open netplwiz
- Untick 'Users must enter a username and password...'
- Open regedit as Administrator
- Browse to

  ```
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
  ```
- Create a new string `DefaultPassword` and write the user's password as value.

**Run bash/cron loop on start**

- Create a file called `linux.bat` in `shell:startup`
- Paste:

  ```
  C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -c 'while [ true ]; do sudo /usr/sbin/cron -f; done'
  ```

**Add apps/services to startup on cron**

- Open bash
- `sudo crontab -e`
- Select nano (or any editor you know how to save in)
- Append startup apps such as openssh-server, nginx, mysql, php:

  ```
  PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
  @reboot . $HOME/.profile; /usr/sbin/sshd -D
  #@reboot . $HOME/.profile; service php7.1-fpm start # Uncomment for php7.1 fpm
  #@reboot . $HOME/.profile; service mysql start # Uncomment for mysql/mariadb
  #@reboot . $HOME/.profile; service nginx start # Uncomment for nginx
  ```
- Save and exit: <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>, then press <kbd>y</kbd> and <kbd>enter</kbd>.

**Reboot the Linux subsystem without rebooting Windows**

- Open bash or SSH in

  ```
  sudo service ssh restart
  ```
- This will close the current instance and create a new one applying cron.

**Extra - Install PHP 7.1 (not quite as straight forward)**

- Run the commands below for a pretty standard setup:

  ```
  mkdir /run/php && chmod -R 777 /run/php
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php && sudo apt update
  PHPV=7.1 && sudo apt install --allow-unauthenticated -y php${PHPV}-fpm php${PHPV}-gd php${PHPV}-json php${PHPV}-mysqlnd php${PHPV}-curl php${PHPV}-intl php${PHPV}-mcrypt php${PHPV}-imagick php${PHPV}-zip php${PHPV}-xml php${PHPV}-mbstring
  ```
- Run the command below for an 'OwnCloud' setup:

  ```
  PHPV=7.1 && apt install --allow-unauthenticated -y php${PHPV}-redis redis-server php${PHPV}-ldap php${PHPV}-smbclient
  ```

**Extra - Install nginx webserver**

- Run the commands below for a base setup with PHP7.1:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable
  sudo apt update && sudo apt -y install nginx
  sudo sed -i 's:access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;:access_log off;:g' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
  sudo sed -i '/index index.html/c\\tindex index.html index.php index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;' /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
  STR='}\n\n\tlocation ~ \.php$ {\n\t\tinclude snippets\/fastcgi-php.conf;\n\t\tfastcgi_pass unix:\/var\/run\/php\/php7.1-fpm.sock;\n\t}'
  sudo sed -i "0,/}/s//$STR\n/" /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
  sudo service nginx restart
  ```

**Extra - Install mariadb's mysql database**

- Run the commands below for a mysql database server:

  ```
  RELEASE=`lsb_release -a | tail -1 | cut -f2`
  sudo apt install software-properties-common
  sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0xF1656F24C74CD1D8
  sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=i386,amd64,ppc64el] https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.3/ubuntu $RELEASE main"
  sudo apt update && sudo apt --allow-unauthenticated -y install mariadb-server
  ```
- When prompted, set a root database user password.

Comment: That is very clever! and precise instructions, thanks.
Is there a way to avoid skipping "sudo" password entirely?

Comment: I don't recommend using the Linux subsystem anymore. The app compatibility sucks, it's unstable and the tools don't all work as well as they could - bash integration, etc. Instead use msys2, it provides you with a great bash shell and will allow you to install a lot of apps via its pacman package manager - Best of all, all of the apps are .exe's. All you need to do is add the bin directories to your environment variables in Windows. I use linux commands in windows and vice versa now. All of my Windows scripting is done in bash.

Answer (score 3):

@Poma and @Hintron answers are great.

I would like to extend description of last point how to add ssh task in Windows Task Scheduler as it requires switching some options:

- Run "Task Scheduler". On the left list select "Task Scheduler (Local)", then go to "Action" menu and "Create Task".
- General tab:

  - Name: "ssh"
  - Select "Run whether user is logged on or not"
- Triggers tab:

  - New

    - Begin the task: "At startup"
- Actions tab:

  - New

    - Program/script: C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe
    - Add arguments (optional): -c "sudo /usr/sbin/service ssh start"
- Conditions:

  - Unselect "Start the task only if the computer is on AC power
- Settings

  - Unselect "Stop the task if it runs longer than

It is used direct bash invocation. There is no need to wrap it in vbs or powershell scripts.

I use service command for reasons that @Hintron explained. Additionally direct sshd invocation gives error

> Missing privilege separation directory: /var/run/sshd

In such case it should be added this entry by `sudo visudo` command

```
ALL ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service ssh *
```

Also notice that here all users (first column) can start or stop sshd. If your are only one user of this Windows machine, then it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

@poma 's answer is very good, and is what my answer is based off of. I want to add some improvements to it, though:

- Use **`service`** instead of calling `sshd` directly: `'sudo service ssh start'` instead of `'sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -D'`. That way, even if you call the script multiple times, there will only be at most one `sshd` process. Also, it's easy to kill it with another script that runs `'sudo service ssh stop'`. In the sudoers file, you simply need to replace `/usr/sbin/sshd -D` with `/usr/sbin/service`.
- If you *are* set on calling `sshd` directly, **get rid of the `-D` option**, because that will put a process in the foreground indefinitely. If you don't believe me, just do `top` and you will see an `init` and a `sudo` process for each time you called the script. Don't forget to remove the `-D` option in the sudoers file as well!
- Use **PowerShell** instead of vbs! Create a file called `autostartsshd.ps1` and paste in the following: `bash -c 'sudo service ssh start'`. To execute the script, right click it and click `Run with PowerShell`.

Another stack overflow question has similar steps: https://superuser.com/a/1114162/182590

Hope that helps someone :)

Comment: Are you sure this will work? Running sshd in the foreground was intentional to keep bash session open (there will be no problems with multiple instances because duplicates will fail to start). If you just run `sudo service ssh start` and then close bash it will kill ssh daemon. At least that's what it did at the moment of writing my guide.

Comment: @Poma With the latest update to Windows 10, Linux applications can now run in the background, so I think this should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

put `bash -c "echo [password] | service ssh start"` in Windows startup script, and use your own sudo password to substitute [password]

Comment: You can't just pipe a password to a sudo prompt (not that your command even includes the necessary `sudo` keyword that your sentence implies). This just doesn't work. Not that you should ever store your password in plaintext anyways!