# How to make WSL run services at startup

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After searching this site and various Q, it is clear that services and `systemd` is not available for WSL. I need to run a program in WSL every time I start my PC so I read this page on how to use crontab: [How to run Ubuntu service on Windows (at startup)?](https://superuser.com/questions/1112007/how-to-run-ubuntu-service-on-windows-at-startup|) Super User  but I got confused because the format does not tally with the format in crontab.

In addition, that particular question was specific for SSH servers which requires that the security aspect if considered and dealth with resulting in overcomplication of steps. Irrespective, the steps explored in that qusetion have been tried and they did not work. In addition, that question is highly specific to SSH servers whilst this question deals with a general enviromental requirement i. I need to know HOW to run services in WSL (which may include but is not limited to SSH serrvers)

In effect - A more simplified solution is required than [How to run Ubuntu service on Windows (at startup)?](https://superuser.com/questions/1112007/how-to-run-ubuntu-service-on-windows-at-startup) provides.

However this is my cron:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
PATH=cd /usr/local/src/:cd xmr-stak-cpu:cd bin/
@reboot . sudo ./xmr-stak-cpu
```

I have also done this:

Run bash/cron loop on start

Create a file called linux.bat in shell:startup

```
Paste: C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -c 'while [ true ]; do sudo /usr/sbin/cron -f; done'
```

It does not work.

How can I run a service in WSL? Or is there a way to use Windows?

Because in Windows I have tried the following: using https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/612

```
Run: When the computer starts, 
Action: Start a program, 
Program: c:\Windows\system32\bash.exe, 
Arguments: -c "sudo  /xmr-stak-cpu/bin/xmr-stak-cpu -D"
Start in:  /usr/local/src/
```

And as you guessed, it still does not work. Frankly I wish I could do this in WSL because it is my preferred way but I will take any way.

I have a workstation with 96GB RAM and as such I will prefer to use this as the dual Linux/Windows machine and not my puny laptop.

I have tasks on both Linux and Windows and really need/prefer the Linux solution provided by Windows.

I have reviewed the other question and there is a package called Mysys that seems to provide a solution however this departs from the integration provided by Microsoft which was a great way forward.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run Ubuntu service on Windows (at startup)?](https://superuser.com/questions/1112007/how-to-run-ubuntu-service-on-windows-at-startup)

Comment: It is NOT a possible duplicate but an extension of it. The routines explored in that question are way beyond what I need. In addition, this is a specific quation atht also refers to that question. You did not read that question, did you?

Comment: Checking your question, you are running `sudo ... xmr-stak-cpu` using a scheduled task. -- Have you ran `visudo` and included the `%sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: /xmr-stak-cpu/bin/xmr-stak-cpu` to avoid problems with the command asking for a password? Do you (really) need the sudo? can you run the miner without sudo privileges?

Answer (score 52):

My example with mysql service

1. Create line in `/etc/sudoers` (at WSL to prevent asking password):

   ```
    %sudo   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service mysql start
   ```
2. Create `.bat` file in Windows startup directory with this line (dir find here: <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and `shell:startup`):

   ```
    wsl sudo service mysql start
   ```

After restarting the service, it will start automatically.

Comment: why `*` and not just `start` ?

Comment: This is the simplest solution by far, and still flexible enough to start anything.

Comment: Instead of creating a `.bat` script you can alternatively create a task in Windows Task Scheduler and set the command `wsl sudo service mysql start` there.

Comment: **Important note:** Do not name the `.bat` file like the command you are using inside (eg. `wsl.bat`)

Comment: Create line in `sudo nano /etc/sudoers`

Comment: @jalescardoso, no, don't edit the file that way. [Always use `visudo` to edit `/etc/sudoers`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/27594/12606). (This will use your system default editor, which might be `nano` or `vi` or anything else.)

Comment: Changes to the sudoers are not needed, neither sudo to call service, simply use `wsl -u root`.

Comment: @kanlukasz why?

Comment: @YSC Because if you name your batch file `wsl.bat` and only refer to `wsl.exe` as `wsl` in your script, your script will call itself (because now `wsl` refers to itself, `wsl.bat`, masking `wsl.exe`). This leads to an infinite loop that will spawn hundreds or thousands of processes.

Comment: worth an [edit] ;) @Phistrom

Answer (score 45):

*Update:  WSL now includes the ability to enable Systemd, which can (as the original question asked) obviously be used to run services when a WSL distribution starts.  However, if that's your only reason for needing Systemd, the answer below may be a better option, as it avoids the additional overhead and complexity of Systemd*

With the release of Windows 11, a new feature has been added to WSL to address this.  This feature is now also available to Windows 10 users if you install [WSL from the Microsoft Store](https://aka.ms/wslstorepage) (requires [KB5020030](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/november-15-2022-kb5020030-os-builds-19042-2311-19043-2311-19044-2311-and-19045-2311-preview-237a9048-f853-4e29-a3a2-62efdbea95e2), which should be available under *Optional Updates*).

To run any arbitrary command when WSL starts, create or edit (as `sudo`) `/etc/wsl.conf` with the following contents:

```
[boot]
command = <command to run as root>; <other command to run as root>
```

If you run a service using this method (e.g. `cron` or `sshd`) please note that the WSL distribution will still auto-terminate when the last process that was started *interactively* completes.  You can see more discussion (and a workaround using `keychain`) for this in my answer to the Ask Ubuntu question [Is it possible to run a WSL app in the background?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1435938/1165986).

For instance:

```
[boot]
command="service ssh start; service cron start"
```

These commands run as root, so no need to use `sudo` with a password.

Note that (currently, at least) if you attempt have multiple `command=` lines, only the *last* will be executed.  If you need multiple commands to run at boot, separate them with a semicolon as above.

If you need these services to start at *Windows* login, simply create a scheduled task at login for `wsl true`.  This will start your WSL instance, triggering the `boot` commands above.

Comment: This is great, thanks. Shame that it's yet another feature that isn't backported to Windows 10.

Comment: Awesome! Should be top answer..

Comment: @Morphit And now it is backported! ;-)

Answer (score 33):

In WSL, the linux distributions run only after a first linux command is invoked. If you wanna run a linux deamon (a service) you must configure the server in linux and run any command in that linux distribution.

There are many pages and answers that show [how to create a script to start a WSL linux when your computer starts](https://superuser.com/questions/1112007/how-to-run-ubuntu-service-on-windows-at-startup?noredirect=1&lq=1).

- There is a [wsl-autostart VBS script](https://github.com/troytse/wsl-autostart) that you can use. You can install the script and change the `commands.txt` with custom linux commands.
- There is a [step by step tutorial](https://gist.github.com/dentechy/de2be62b55cfd234681921d5a8b6be11) to start automatically an ssh server on WSL.
- There are also options to create policies to run the program as an initial tasks (using the `gpedit.msc` command) or a scheduled task that run at startup (using the `taskschd.msc`).

---

**NOTE:** If your program must be executed with `sudo`, you must configure it to start the program without asking a password.

- Run `visudo` in the linux and add a line at the end of the file: `%sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: /full/path/to/program`

Comment: +1 for the wsl-autostart script. Only downside is this triggers a UAC prompt on every start up... :/

Comment: ...so the way I did this was to use the wsl-autostart script, but skip the instructions that tell you to create a startup item in the registry. Instead, use Task Scheduler to create a task the runs the `start.vbs` file on login with maximum user priviliges. I can now run this to quietly start the cron service in WSL every time I start my machine- works like a dream ;)

Answer (score 11):

Another option:

#### 1) Create a startup file in Linux at `/etc/init-wsl`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo booting
service ssh start
```

and make the script executable

`chmod +x /etc/init-wsl`

#### 2) Schedule executing this file at windows boot or log on

[image: test]

Since `wsl.exe` is able to run commands inside the wsl distro, we simply schedule
to run this file through the command `wsl -u root /etc/init-wsl`. If you have multiple distros, you might want to specify which one with a `-d` flag, for instance `wsl -d Ubuntu-20.04 -u root /etc/init-wsl`

Comment: /etc should contain only configurations. Better use /usr/local/bin

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for your question, it guided me towards this solution. This is my complete, generalized- and particular solution. It consist of 3 steps:

1. Create a cronjob
2. Run/enable the cronjob service at startup
3. Remove prompting for password to start the cronjob service automatically.

In reality your problem is already solved with just step 2 and 3, but since you tried to do it with a cronjob, I also added that step for completeness.

**1. Creating a functioning cronjob:**

1. Browse to folder `/etc/`
2. Then in folder `/etc/` enter:`sudo nano crontab`
3. In that file named crontab enter your command.
4. E.g.: `*/1 * * * * root touch /var/www/myFile`
5. To create a file named `myFile` in location `/var/www/` every minute.
6. For completeness: `*/1 * * * * root touch /var/www/myFile` would mean: create that file every 1st minute of the hour.

An example of the `crontab` file could look like (I only added the last line, the rest was already there in my setup):

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
*/2 * * * * root touch /var/www/myFile
```

**2. Enabling cronjob service**

To run a command automatically at startup of WSL Ubuntu 16.04 you can:

1. cd to `/home/<your ubuntu user name>`
2. `sudo nano .bashrc`
3. The text editor nano then creates/opens a file `.bashrc`
4. In that file a lot of examples can be shown already, to just execute your command upon startup of the WSL ubuntu 16.04, write your command on the first line of the `.bashrc` file.
5. For example:`echo "hello world"` as shown in the picture below.
6. *For your particular problem, the particular solution would be to enter the line:`sudo ./xmr-stak-cpu`*
7. Close the editor with: `ctrl+x`
8. Save the file with `Y`
9. Exit ubuntu
10. Restart ubuntu and verify indeed the hello world is printed before your username.

[![An example command in .bashrc that is executed upon boot of WSL
    ubuntu.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rn3J.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rn3J.png)

For example this could be what your `.bashrc` looks like after you edited it: (I only added the first line on top, the rest was already there in my setup.)

```
sudo -i service cron start
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
        # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
        # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
        # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
        color_prompt=yes
    else
        color_prompt=
    fi
fi
```

You can replace the `hello world`command with `sudo service cron start` to enable cronjob service. However then you are still required to enter your password manually.

**3. Removing prompt for password:**
Using: https://askubuntu.com/questions/147241/execute-sudo-without-password

1. Open WSL ubuntu 16.04 (terminal)
2. `sudo visudo`
3. At the bottom of the file add line:
   `<your WSL ubuntu username> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`
4. E.g with username zq you would add the following line to the bottom of the file:
5. `zq ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`
6. ctrl+x to exit
7. `y` followed by `<enter>` to save.
8. Then again, close ubuntu and re-open it and verify
9. The cron service is running automatically when you boot/open WSL ubuntu 16.04 without prompting for password.
10. (you can check with command: `sudo service cron status`.)

The code to prevent prompting for password at boot would for example look like (I only added the last line, the rest was already there in my setup):

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/s$
# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
%sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/cron
zq ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Working towards this solution, I learned cronjobs are intended for things to run periodically rather than at specific events such as startup. To run things at startup in WSL you can use the file  `/home/<username>/.bashrc`.

Comment: Copy a section from `.bashrc` file in your answer so that reader get to know how it looks like after editing.

Comment: @Biswapriyo, thank you for your feedback. Initially I added a screenshot of that code but could not get it working. So I pasted the actual code.

Comment: (1) Your answer is very confusing.  As far as I can tell, your bottom line is to use `.bashrc` and not `crontab`.  So why is approximately 60% of your answer talking about `crontab`?  (2) The question says “I need to run a program in WSL every time I start my PC”.  Your answer doesn’t run the program until the user starts WSL and logs in.  This seems not to answer the question.  (3) There’s no reason for a user to use ``sudo`` to edit their own `.bashrc`.  If anything, that can cause problems.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (4) Your answer describes how to disable password verification of ``sudo`` across the board.  This is widely regarded as a bad idea.  Note that other answers have showed how to do this for only the required program.  (5) When ``cron`` was written, >40 years ago, it handled only scheduled, periodic tasks.  Since then, it has been extended to handle commands at boot time.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I see, all solutions here run just the moment, the user logs in. This might not exactly match the need `as windows starts`.
Just to mention: You might also use the windows task planner for execution of jobs by a given trigger. Maybe you just wanna give it a try.
**But now the news solution, which I use on my self**: With the software [Non sucking service manager](http://nssm.cc) you can run any program as a windows service. With that, I wrapped the startup of `jupyter-notebook` within WSL2 (also worked fine in WSL1) as a service while starting up the computer, without loggin in - in the context of a user.

If you like, have a look at the following dumped commands as an example. But do not fear, you can also use a GUI.

```
nssm.exe install Jupyter c:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe
nssm.exe set Jupyter AppParameters "--distribution Debian --exec jupyter-notebook --no-browser --NotebookApp.token=''  --NotebookApp.disable_check_xsrf=True"
nssm.exe set Jupyter AppDirectory C:\Users\USER\jupyter
nssm.exe set Jupyter AppExit Default Restart
nssm.exe set Jupyter AppNoConsole 1
nssm.exe set Jupyter AppPriority IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS
nssm.exe set Jupyter AppStdout C:\Users\USER\.jupyter\jupyter.stdout
nssm.exe set Jupyter AppStderr C:\Users\USER\.jupyter\jupyter.stderr
nssm.exe set Jupyter AppRotateFiles 1
nssm.exe set Jupyter AppRotateOnline 1
nssm.exe set Jupyter AppTimestampLog 1
nssm.exe set Jupyter DisplayName Jupyter
nssm.exe set Jupyter Start SERVICE_DELAYED_AUTO_START
nssm.exe set Jupyter Type SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
```

As you see, also LogFile creation and rotation is possible.

Answer (score 3):

Download this -> https://github.com/troytse/wsl-autostart

And instead of following the instructions to set up in the registry/group policy/taskschd, just drop a shortcut for `start.vbs` in your startup folder:

`"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"`

Or the system startup folder

`"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp"`

Works great!

Answer (score 3):

The solution making changes only inside of WSL distro, allowing you to get services started(if they haven't been started yet) each time you launch your shell:

1. (taken from [wsl-autostart](https://github.com/troytse/wsl-autostart)) Edit `/etc/sudoers`:
   Find the part of the text under `# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command`
   comment and insert the following line(-s) in the end there:

   `%sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/<service name>` - for each service
2. Edit `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` or whatever else (depending on the shell you use), add line(-s):

   `ps -C <service name> &> /dev/null || sudo /etc/init.d/<service name> start &> /dev/null` - for each service

   Check it carefully as `<service name>` in the first and the second parts of the
   expression can differ.

Hope that this solution will fit your needs. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This consists of two important steps:

**1) Disable password prompt in for sudo in WSL (under WSL)**

```
sudo visudo
#add at the bottom
yourUserName ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

**2) Task Scheduler/`taskschd.msc` (under Windows)**

Create a basic task to run at windows startup with as many commands in the following form:

```
wsl sudo service ssh start
wsl sudo service nginx start
#...etc.
```

Comment: This is a good approach, since you have all control whether it should be started at startup or at user's logon, specify a delay etc.

Answer (score 2):

systemd on startup is now supported (WSL2, Windows 11) - add the following to your `/etc/wsl.conf`:

```
[boot]
systemd = true
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User!  While this is somewhat correct, there's a lot more information that is needed in order for someone to do this.  This is not a feature that is supported by default on Windows 11 WSL2 -- It requires a recent release of WSL, which you have to upgrade to manually for most Windows systems.  See [this Stack Overflow Community Wiki answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73833858/11810933) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Noticed the same. Have to start my corn, nginx, mysql, elasticsearch etc. etc. manually after every reboot. It's because `systemd` is not supported on WSL. I am currently using WSL 2.

My simple solution to this is a bash script to start all the services one after another

For example `start_services.sh` (all in a single line with `;` at last):

```
sudo service cron start ; sudo service php7.4-fpm start ; sudo service elasticsearch start ; sudo service mysql start ; sudo service nginx start ;
```

Similarly, I have other scripts `to restart` and `to stop` the services.

Answer (score 0):

Since the introduction of the [boot] section in the wsl.conf file, this has gotten dramatically easier.  You can run systemd, but if you don't need the power of it, you can also run an old-school /etc/rc system.  It's compatible with /etc/init.d, and while you can't get it to behave properly with runlevels (since they don't exist on WSL), you *can* use the /etc/rc file as a boot script.

Add the following two files and restart your wsl instance, and your init.d scripts will now work automatically.  Newly installed services will behave properly as well.

/etc/wsl.conf

```
[boot]
command="/etc/rc"
```

/etc/rc

```
#!/bin/sh

# Start system services
for i in /etc/rc3.d/S*; do
  if [ -x $i ]; then
    $i start
  fi
done

# Run /etc/rc.local if it exists
if [ -x /etc/rc.local ] ; then
  /etc/rc.local
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a comment to the [answer by @NotTheDr01ds](https://superuser.com/a/1685207/691040), but I don't how enough reputation yet to comment.

I just installed a WSL2 distribution on Windows 10 19045.3086 and discovered it has systemd supported and enabled by default. And the [other answer by @NotTheDr01ds](https://askubuntu.com/a/1436045/392634)
indeed "hackily" allows you to keep WSL running after logging in and out. However, if you want your systemd services started on boot, the suggested solution to `wsl true` on boot via a scheduled task won't work: it gets the services started, but the wsl distro terminates in a short while. Looks like starting a service via the "default Linux shell" (which happens when you run `wsl true`) doesn't work, and you need the "login shell". Not sure why, but perhaps the default one bypasses the init of the login shell, or daemons started this way aren't considered "interactive". Anyway, the solution is to use the login shell command on boot, e.g.:

```
wsl --shell-type login true
```

or

```
wsl -d Ubuntu-22.04 --shell-type login true
```