# How to run command when starting a machine in WSL2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wsl2

I realize that WSL2 does not have a systemd  which is responsible for starting process, but my goal to run a command when i start a wsl instance(machine )

```
wsl -l -v
  NAME            STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-20.04    Stopped         2
  kali-linux      Stopped         2
  Ubuntu-22.04    Stopped         2
```

how do I run a command once when i start any of the following machines

I tried to edit the `/etc/wsl.conf` and add the following

```
[boot]
command="ping 10.0.0.8 && service docker restart "
```

but this does not seem to help and I don't see anything on the ip `10.0.0.8`

I tried editing cron jobs with `crontab -e`  but this does not work because of the reason mentioned in the top

I start the machines using the command `wsl --distribution Ubuntu-20.04` and i kill them using `wsl --shutdown`  but this does not seem to cause the `wsl.conf` to run the `command`

Comment: How about sticking it into .bashrc or .profile

Comment: @cup where are these files located  at

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few pointers ...

First, you don't mention what Windows version you are running.  Windows 11 is required to use the WSL `[boot]` feature in `/etc/wsl.conf` *(<sup>Update note:</sup> No longer the case.  Please see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1685207/1210833) for details)*.

But even if you have Windows 11, your example would still have a few problems:

```
[boot]
command="ping 10.0.0.8 && service docker restart "
```

First, `ping 10.0.0.8`, as you point out, is an interactive command.  The `command` that is executed does not have access to a terminal, so you'll need to redirect the output if you want to capture the results.

Second, `ping` will typically "run forever" in a normal scenario.  The `ping` is never going to "finish" so that your `service docker restart` is executed.  You can reproduce the same thing at the command-line.

Third, since the boot `command` only executes once when the WSL instance is starting, there's really no need for a `service ... restart`.  Perhaps not a huge deal, since `restart` will typically `start` if it isn't already, but I *think* I've seen some service scripts that will refuse to `restart` if the service isn't currently started.  I can't remember how the Docker init service is scripted.

###### Step 1:  Capture ping output

So (assuming you are on Windows 11), try, for starters:

```
[boot]
command="ping 10.0.0.8 >> /var/log/mybootping.log"
```

Exit your Ubuntu/WSL2 instance and, from PowerShell:

```
wsl -l -v
# Confirm your distribution name -- Change it below if needed
wsl --terminate Ubuntu-20.04
wsl ~ -d Ubuntu-20.04
```

Then, check `cat /var/log/mybootping.log`.  You should see the results of the ping.  Note that it will continue to run, and the log grow, until you either exit the instance or `kill` the `ping` process.

###### Step 2:  Allow ping to exit

You can limit this by changing the command to `ping -c 4 10.0.0.8` to repeat the ping only 4 times.  That way, `ping` will exit on its own.

###### Step 3:  Capture errors from ping

But let's say that you mistype the commandline:

```
[boot]
command="ping -c 10.0.0.8 >> /var/log/mybootping.log"
```

Oops, I left off the number of retries for the `-c` flag.  Note -- I actually *did* make this mistake when testing this.  But `/var/log/mybootping.log` didn't get the output since it goes to stderr instead of stdout.

Best to make this:

```
[boot]
command="ping -c 4 10.0.0.8 >> /var/log/mybootping.log 2>&1"
```

That will capture/append both error and output to the log.

###### Step 4:  Add Docker service

At this point, with `ping` being able to exit with the `-c` argument, you can add the Docker service.

```
[boot]
command="ping -c 4 10.0.0.8 >> /var/log/mybootping.log 2>&1 && service docker start"
```

###### Step 5:  Capture output and error from *both* ping and service

But what if you just want to capture *all* output from the boot command?

```
[boot]
command="exec 1>>/var/log/wslboot.log && exec 2>&1 && echo -------------------- && date && ping -c 4 10.0.0.8 && service docker start"
```

##### For Windows 10

If you don't have Windows 11, then, as mentioned above, you won't be able to use the `[boot]` feature of `wsl.conf`.

You can either:

- Add the commands to your user's `~/.bashrc` as I mention in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1701903/1210833)
- Run a one-time "boot" command manually for WSL.  For example, from PowerShell:

  ```
  wsl ~ -u root -d Ubuntu-20.04 -e sh -c "ping -c 4 10.0.0.8 && service docker start"
  ```

  Since the output will appear in this case, we can skip all of the output/error capture that we used in the `[boot]` command.

  If you have a service that doesn't fork (background itself), like `dockerd` (from the comments), then you'll need to execute it with `nohup`.  Something like:

  ```
  wsl ~ -u root -d Ubuntu-20.04 -e nohup sh -c "dockerd &"
  ```

  Any output will be in `/root/nohup.out`.  If you want to direct it elsewhere, it starts to get a bit more complicated:

  ```
  wsl ~ -u root -d Ubuntu-20.04 -e sh -c "nohup sh -c 'dockerd &' >> /var/log/dockerd-nohup.out"
  ```

  I might be wrong, but I believe there's a WSL bug that makes this a bit more difficult.  From what I can tell, WSL is overly aggressive about reaping (not yet) orphaned subprocesses of the shell into `init`.

Comment: Many thanks for this useful answer, when I try to run `wsl ~ -u root -d Ubuntu-20.04 -e sh -c "dockerd &"  ` this will not run the docker deamon but if i remove the `&` it works fine but the powershell window is filled with the docker deamon log any idea how to fix this

Comment: @loaded_dypper Can you do `wsl ~ -u root -d Ubuntu-20.04 -e sh -c "service docker start"`?  That should daemonize it properly, I would think.  Alternatively, `wsl ~ -u root -d Ubuntu-20.04 -e nohup sh -c "dockerd &"` or (to capture output) `wsl ~ -u root -d Ubuntu-20.04 -e sh -c "nohup sh -c 'dockerd &' >> /var/log/dockerd-nohup.out"`

Comment: I'll add those to the answer for readability (and so that I can hopefully find them again myself).  That was a hard one, btw - Solution was in [this comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3670#issuecomment-634226247) on Github.

Answer (score 0):

You could use .bashrc or .profile.

When a WSL prompt is started, these files are located in the /home/ directory of the user.

Comment: is it ran as root ?

Comment: It is run as the current user.  If you want to run as root, create the file, then su to root and set the sticky bit to the script you wish to run.

Comment: also, look into [/etc/profile and /etc/bashrc](https://bencane.com/2013/09/16/understanding-a-little-more-about-etcprofile-and-etcbashrc/)

Comment: Detailed info on what you can do with Bash - www.tldp.org -> Bash guides - see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)