# Verify that config value applied in WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

WSL configuration can be set in `wsl.conf` (for distro) or `.wslconfig` (global) based on the [Advanced Settings doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config). Is there a way to verify that a value has been applied?

Something like `echo $propName` in bash/zsh?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not via an environment variable.  I'll be honest - When I first started typing this answer (an hour+ ago), I thought that might be a good idea for a [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues) for the WSL team.  But then I wondered if it would really be useful -- An environment variable would probably just tell you if the value was *parsed*, but not really if it had the intended *effect*.  Still, if you want to suggest it, please do so, of course.

However, I'd recommend confirming via observation of the intended effect, whenever possible.  I know this isn't "ideal", but, for instance:

##### For `/etc/wsl.conf`:

`[automount]`:

- `enabled` defaults to `true`.  Setting to `false` would be easily observable by the lack of mounts at `/mnt/c`, `/mnt/d`, etc.
- Likewise, `root` is easily observable by checking to make sure the location of the `C:` drive mount is in this location.
- `mountFsTab` defaults to `true`.  Setting it to `false` would be observable by the lack of any mounts in `/etc/fstab`, but only if `/etc/fstab` was populated.
- `options` can be seen via `mount | grep drvfs`, assuming that `enabled` is `true`.

`[interop]`:

- `enabled` defaults to `true`.  If set to `false`, running `/mnt/c/Windows/System32/notepad.exe` should result in an exit code of 1.  It's ironic that I found that this [appears to be broken on the latest WSL releases](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8932) while writing this answer.  It definitely leads credence towards the possible need for a "was this setting parsed" verification as you are asking.
- `appendWindowsPath` defaults to `true`.  With apologies for stating the obvious, it's simple to check after setting it to `false` that the Windows path is not present by `echo $PATH`.

`[boot]`:

- `systemd` (currently, and hopefully always) defaults to `false`.  If set to `true`, a `ps axjf` should (at least in recent releases) show `/sbin/init` instead of `/init`.  And, of course, `sudo systemctl status` should work.
- `command` is a bit more difficult.  Of course, it's easy to verify that the `command` is being run by using a simple test like `touch /root/abc`, but debugging error conditions a more complicated command may require a bit of [redirection gynmnastics](https://superuser.com/a/1717840/1210833).

`[network]`:

- All current settings in this section generate messages in the kernel ring buffer during startup of the distribution (at least on recent WSL releases).  If you change any of them from their default value, you can verify that the setting was parsed with something like:

  ```
  dmesg | grep resolv.conf
  dmesg | grep hosts
  dmesg | grep hostname
  ```

  If WSL has detected the `wsl.conf` change, you'll see something like the following:

  ```
  [42221.879637] WSL (1) WARNING: /etc/hosts updating disabled in /etc/wsl.conf
  ```

  Note:  It's probably better to do this after a `wsl --shutdown` to limit the results to those from the current boot.  A `sudo dmesg --clear` coupled with a `wsl --terminate <distro>` also works.

`[user]`:

- Only one setting here, `default`, which can be confirmed after exiting and terminating the distribution via:

  ```
  wsl ~ -d <distroname> -e whoami
  ```

  The `-d <distroname` is, of course, optional for the default distribution.

##### For `.wslconfig`:

- `kernel`:  Can typically be verified with `uname -a`.  If you do build your own kernel, I do recommend that you change its name slightly so that you can identify it as your own in the `uname` results.
- `swap` and `memory`:  Will be displayed by `htop` and other mechanisms.
- `processors`:  Shown by `lscpu`
- `kernelCommandLine`:  Shown by changes in `/proc/sys` values.
- `swapFile`:  Look for the creation of the named file, of course, but I'm not quite sure how to troubleshoot the parsing if the swap disk doesn't change.
- `localhostForwarding`:  A bit more difficult to verify reliably if you suspect that there may be an issue with your localhost forwarding.  On recent WSL Preview releases (Windows 11 only, installed from the Microsoft Store), you can also enable the `debugShell` option in `.wslconfig`:

  ```
  [wsl2]
  localhostForwarding=false
  debugShell=true
  ```

  Issue a `wsl --shutdown`.  When you restart WSL2, you'll get a second console window that allows you to view the virtual machine in which your distribution is running.  In that console, use:

  ```
  ps axjf | grep port-tracker | grep -v grep
  ```

  If `localhostForwarding` is enabled, you should see a process running that looks something like:

  ```
  localhost --port-tracker-fd 7
  ```

  If `localhostForwarding` is disabled, the process should not be running.
- `guiApplications`:  When `true` (default), `/mnt/wslg` will be mounted and populated.  When `false`, `/mnt/wslg` will be empty or not exist.  Additional debugging can be done from the `debugShell` mentioned above.  The `WSLGd` daemon will only run in that VM when `guiApplications=true`.
- `vmIdleTimeout` can be observed as noted [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/discussions/8659).
- `nestedVirtualization` and `pageReporting`:  I don't have a good answer for.